# Incorrect Longitude and Latitude

Tags: geolocation

The Geolocation Longitude and Latitude coordinates I am getting out of Salesforce are not the same as the Google coordinates for the same address.
When I load an Account or Contact address the Map generates correctly and the pinpoint is 100% correct. I have created the longitude and Latitude fields are custom formula fields.

When I check the log/lat in SF I am getting mixed results I can be 1 or 10km out... I have had the odd address within 500mtrs, but this is no good when you want to use this data for a  radius search or use the Geoloaction to send a service person to a location.

Has anyone else come across this and did you find a solution to your problem

Answer (score 1):

Well, We don't know which address provider API Salesforce is using to get latitude and longitude. So it would be hard to get it fixed from it.

If you think Google API is better, then you can do is call Google geolocation API from Trigger when address is added/changes in Future/Queuable.

There is blog for it: You can refer it.

Src: https://matheusgoncalves.com/geolocation-salesforce-google-api/

Answer (score 0):

I came across this for addresses with a particular postalcode - BT which is Belfast in Northern Ireland. Eg BT19 7QY has a Google Value of 54.6439855422, -2.7426800000
but a data integration value of 54.64406625002473, -5.667416615228273 (mainland UK).

When I know of an incorrect set of coords I override them using the following method:
I created 'verified billing address latitude' and '...longitude' fields.
I then changed the formula on 'billing address latitude' and '...longitude' to be:

```
IF( BLANKVALUE(Verified_Billing_Address_Latitude__c ,0)=0, BillingLatitude, Verified_Billing_Address_Latitude__c )
```

and

```
IF( BLANKVALUE(Verified_Billing_Address_Longitude__c ,0)=0, BillingLongitude, Verified_Billing_Address_Longitude__c )
```